# VK Audio API: как получить информацию о плейлисте

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как получить информацию (колличество прослушиваний, url на автора и тд) о плейлисте по его id/url?

Answer (score 0):

В 2016 году VK отключила API для работы с [аудио](https://dev.vk.com/reference/roadmap#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20API%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE). Узнать напрямую информацию через id или ссылку **нельзя**. Есть возможность получить данные, например, в сообщении, как [вложение](https://dev.vk.com/reference/objects/audio), когда пользователь отправляет сообщение с музыкой.

[Подробнее](https://dev.vk.com/ru/reference/roadmap?ref=old_portal#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20API%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE) об этой проблеме на странице *roadmap* в документации.

---

*Приложение же ВК работает через апи, почему я не могу эти методы через токен оффициального приложения?*

**НЕТ**, тогда вы нарушаете [Правила пользования Сайтом ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/terms):

> #### 6. Обязанности Пользователя ВКонтакте
>
> 6.7. Создаваемые Пользователями приложения API должны использовать **только опубликованные на Сайте методы API**, а также ID, защищенный ключ и сервисный ключ доступа, указанные в настройках данных приложений. **Использование других методов API**, а также ID, **защищенного ключа и сервисного ключа доступа приложений API** третьих лиц, в т.ч. **приложения API Администрации Сайта, строго запрещено**. Пользователь обязуется регулярно проверять перечень разрешённых методов и незамедлительно вносить корректировки в функциональность своих приложений API в соответствии с изменениями перечня. **За нарушение настоящего пункта Пользователь несет предусмотренную применимым законодательством, настоящими Правилами и иными документами Администрации Сайта ответственность**. Администрация Сайта при этом оставляет за собой право на защиту собственных прав и законных интересов.

Не нарушаем правила и используем API по назначению.